# Loop changing a string keep failing?

Tags: c++

```
  cin >> n;
  string disks;                                                                                                                                           
  for(i=0; i < n; i++){
      disks[2*i] = 1;
      disks[2*i+1] = 0;  
  }
```

This keeps saying: `string subscript out of range`. Even if I change it to `(n-1)`. I am trying to think of a very simple way to just set this to alternating `1` and `0`s and I cant find it!

Why is this loop causing an error?

Comment: `disks` is an empty string. `disks[i]` is invalid (index out of bounds) for any value of `i`.

Comment: Why are you using `std::string`, and not say `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>`, for storing bits anyway? Strings are designed for storing characters.

Answer (score 1):

When a std::string is default-constructed it's empty; you can't just start writing to it as the underlying storage hasn't been allocated.

Instead, use `string disks(n * 2, '0');` to initialise the string with space for `2 * n` characters. It will be pre-filled with `'0'` (the zeroes), then all you have to do is go through and fill in the ones.

```
cin >> n;
string disks(n * 2, '0');
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    disks[2 * i] = '1';
```

Also note that you need to use `'0'` and `'1'` to get the actual character values.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a string that has no initial value you cannot access it, in your example with `operator[]`. So, the lines:

```
  disks[2*i] = 1;
  disks[2*i+1] = 0;
```

are causing the error, because you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist.

If you want to assign a value to a string use concatenation:

```
disks += "0" + "1";
```

or `push_back()`, `append()`. The sequence of the assigned values will determine which will be at even and odd index.